# How to use EJB Project classes in Dynamic Web Project in JBoss AS 7 at runtime

Tags: jboss, ejb, wicket

i am using Eclipse (JavaEE) and JBoss AS 7 for developping a web application. For the frontend I have a dynamic webproject, using Apache Wicket to create the UI and for the backend I have a EJB Project. Both projects are part of the same eclipse-workspace and running on the same JBoss application server and I try to use  wicketstuff javaee-inject (https://community.jboss.org/wiki/WicketEJBCDIJPAWithJBossAS7) to get the ability to inject EJBs inside of wicket.

I added the EJB Project to the Java Build Path of the Dynamic Web Project, so I can use the `Local-EJB-Interfaces`, defined in the EJB Project. When I run now both Projects on the server, and try to inject a EJB I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` because the `LocalInterface` is unknown. ... My Workarround actually is, that I export my EJB Project as a JAR-File and add it for Deployment Assembly to the Dynamic Web Project. That works, but cant be the correct solution, because the EJB-Project is running then twice on the server.

What else could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, by exporting all interfaces and JPA-Files into a library project (normal Java Project) and put all my projects into an EAR-Project.